# Fullcalendar Events on a Modal

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I was just wondering, is it possible to fetch all the data of events on the day selected on the calendar and show it through a modal? If this is possible, can you help me how to do this? :)

Comment: Well you have the dayClick event and you should have access to your eventSources so at that point it is just an exercise in extracting your data based on your current view dates ('getView').

Comment: @mccainz, thanks mate! I was exploring it quite a while now but then I am stuck at this goto date. I was able to change the view by clicking on a day but it shows the date today and not the date I clicked. Do you have any idea how to do this? :)

Comment: The dayClick event will pass in the date the user clicked http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/

Comment: Thanks mate! :)
I got it a few days back, sorry I haven't been here for a while. Thanks for the help mate! :)
It's much more better than using modal to display the details. :)